# Bottom container is overlaying top when scrolling - tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have two rows in a grid.

these both start down from the top of the page so I didn't use top-0

I want to fix the tabs bar to the top of the container. I do this with fixed and top-20.
This worked.

However when I did it, the lower container which contains the items for this tab, was now overlaying on top of the tabs.

So I did mt-20 for the lower container and this worked. However when I scroll down through the items they rise up and over the tabs, instead of scrolling up and not going into the tabs section.

```
<div className="relative
```

// these are on the same level

// top tabs bar area - I added the fixed and top-20

```
  <div className="relative  sm:overflow-hidden">
      <div className="pb-3 fixed top-20">
```

// list of items - I put mt-20 and it adds the correct distance, but when scrolling it goes over the top tabs

```
  <ul
     role="list"
     className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-4 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-x-8 mt-20"
   >
```

I tried putting a parent div around all these and putting it as fixed.
This just makes it so the ul cannot scroll.

I also tried putting:

```
fixed top-40
```

on the ul element. It positions it under the tabs, but they look cramped (don't take up full width of area. It also makes it so they cannot scroll to see all the items.

EDIT;
I have used z value to get the nav bar on top and changed it's background to white so it covers the items below.
However there are some space above the nav where the items can show when scrolling.

I am trying to put another fixed div just below the z level of the nav bar and have it just white to cover those items.

```
class="lg:fixed z-10 bg-white z-11 top-30"

style=“width: 100%;height: 40px;top: 64.5px;”
```

I have tried this, but it seems a bit manually, and when I resize the screen a bit the exact line is slightly different which shows the items a little.

Comment: Try adding z-10 to the fixed div to give it a higher stack level

Comment: thank you I have used this, but there is still a little area above the nav bar where the items show through. Do you know how I could prevent the items from reaching this area when scrolling, or cover it with a white div? I have updated my answer at the bottom.

Comment: I see you have `mt-20` on the `ul` element which I would try replacing with `pt-20` so it takes the background color.